# Subsidiary Navigator on NetSuite doesn't work with Custom Roles

Tags: netsuite, portlet

When I select the Subsidiary Navigator Portlet on NetSuite, it doesn't work with Custom Roles, only with the Administrator Role. When I say 'doesn't work' I mean that when I click on any Subsidiary, the others Portlets doesn't update from the selection made.

Does anybody knows how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I am not first hand experienced with the "Subsidiary Navigator Portlet"; however you might want to check/change/confirm the "Subsidiary Restrictions" for each of the custom roles.  There are settings for [accessible subsidiaries, and cross-subsidiary record viewing](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/91074/kw/91074).